# Swift Vapor 3 calling a router from inside another

Tags: swift, vapor

I’ve a server application with Vapor 3, I set up three models Book, Author, Publisher, relative routers and controllers with CRUD and relationships (both Author and Publisher have a Sibling relationship with book).
All would be fine was not for the incoming data: the Json I receive has a different data structure, where the publishers and authors are stored in arrays inside the book.

I cannot decode on Book.self because I would lose the data relevant to publishers and authors, so I created BookTotal, which has no representation on the database (no migration) so I could

`req.content.decode(BookTotal.self).flatMap`

At this point I would like to call the save or update functions on the Publisher and Author controllers passing the BookTotal.Publisher and BookTotal.Author array.

But, while I can reach the methods either with something like

```
`PublisherController.Save()`
```

Or

```
    let client = req.make(Client.self)
    let response = client(“path/for/the/router”)
```

I don’t know how to pass them the data. The CRUD methods inside the controllers have Request as parameter but I don’t know how to build one.

```
let newReq = Request()
newReq.content = BookTotal.Author
```

Would be my guess, but Request wants a Container and I don’t know how I should go about that.
I searched around but couldn't find any example/tutorial on such issue.
Am I even on the right path with this?

Answer (score 3):

So you have a couple of options to achieve what you want to do. One option is to rewrite your request handlers in your controllers to accept that data using one of the helper functions. So

```swift
func savePublisher(_ req: Request, data: Publisher) throws -> Future<Publisher>
```

You can then change `router.post("your", "url", use: savePublisher)` to `router.post(Publisher.self, at: "your", "url", use: savePublisher)`. Then if your code you can call that method and pass the data through as needed.

A (potentially) better way would be to extract the code that saves a publisher out into a separate function which you can then call from your `savePublisher` route and your `bookTotal` route. For basic routes this is likely to be the same as the first option, but for most complex routes this is the way to go.

Comment: First of all, thank you 0xTim, it was very kind of you to answer.
And I must also say I feel pretty dumb not to have seen such easy solution.

Comment: [hit return by mistake]
...
Now that you pointed it out to me seems quite obvious.

Regarding your second option, I briefly tried something along those lines but I was held back by the fact that, for example, the .save() method requires a DatabaseConnectable
`publisher.save(on: req)` usually
and don't know if I'm just supposed to pass my original request or what.

Comment: I'd pass down the `Request` all the way - it's what I usually do unless I'm writing a function that may not necessarily no about request (usually in a library). But if you're writing a function for your own app, just use `Request`